# Issue on awk input parameter in ksh

Tags: awk, ksh, parameter

I am running this script:

```
INPUTNAME=ABC.XYZ
FILENAME="Sample.xml"

    awk -v inputName=$INPUTNAME '
      /<machine.*name=/ { f=1 ; m=0 ; res="" }
      f { res = res $0 ORS }
      f && /<details input="inputName"/ { m=1 }
      /<\/machine>/ { f=0 ; if (m) print res $0 }
     ' $FILENAME
```

to get an output like this

```
<machine name="sample1" min="1" max="10" idleTime="300" backend="ABC,XYZ">
                <handler className="com.abc.xyz.qwerty.foo.FooBar" />
                <details input="ABC.XYZ" suggExpiry="30" minExpiry="4" maxExpiry="500"/>
                </machine>
```

but the parameter input is failing. What seems to be wrong in the script?

NOTE:

I ran it with hardcoded values (not using parameters) and it run smoothly

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Please give input and desired output examples.

Comment: variables defined using -v can be used only in the BEGIN block. See man page for awk here -  http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?awk  (search for -v)

Comment: the input and expected output is already provided

Comment: is single quote next to $INPUTNAME with out space a typo ? you MUST have a space.

Comment: @archermar just a typo

Comment: @PhilipMorris Sorry, but I don't see an input example here.

Comment: @chaos the script itself is the input

Comment: @PhilipMorris I don't think you want to edit the script with the script? What is inside `Sample.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure awk will replace a variable by it's value in

```
 f && /<details input="inputName"/
```

you might wish to replace by

```
 f && /<details input="/ && index($2,inputName) > 0
```

## edit:

final awk part should be:

```
    /<machine.*name=/ { f=1 ; m=0 ; res="" }
    f { res = res $0 ORS }
    f && /<details input="/ && index($2,inputName) > 0 { m=1 ;}
    /<\/machine>/ { f=0 ; if (m) print res  ;  } ## last line already in res
```

Comment: I am getting two enclosing tags </machine></machine> in the end

Comment: last line is added twice, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `inputName` is a variable you can *not* use repexp constants `/.../` (like in `f && /<details input="inputName"/`). Instead use dynamic regexps through strings:

```
f && $0 ~ "<details input=" inputName
```

where you concatenate the string `"..."` with variable `inputName`.

(Note: Since you are processing XML, keep in mind, when processing XML end-tags, that in strings any `\` will need an extra level of escaping.)

Comment: This didnt work Janis but the other answer worked for me. Still, I thank you for this.